How to Deploy Cloud Run job By Github Action
I am trying to set up a GitHub action to automatically deploy whenever there's a commit into a Git repository. I followed a tutorial available at this URL.
deploy-to-cloud-run
However, it is creating a Cloud Run service instead of a Cloud Run job. Can anyone help me with setting up GitHub action for a Cloud Run job?
I am trying to set up a GitHub action to automatically deploy whenever there's a commit into a Git repository.

Add this in your action pipeline:
- name: Update Cloud Run Job
  run: |
    IMAGE_NAME=gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/my-cloud-run-job
    gcloud run jobs update my-cloud-run-job \
      --image $IMAGE_NAME \
      --region ${{ secrets.GCP_REGION }} \
      --project ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}

